# In Terraria, when I beat the Wall of Flesh and activate hardmode, do I lose all my stuff?

Tags: terraria

I read online something about how the world changes. Two questions:

- Do I lose my gear I'm carrying?
- Do I lose my house or treasure chests in it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope

Everything you have done is still there, you just get a streak of Hallow and Corruption that both start at spawn location but down in the hell level that go up and to the right and left (randomly which one goes which way) forming a big V.

The mobs that spawn now include the hard mode mobs as well so the world overall is now more dangerous, but you still have all your gear.

Comment: Okay, I'ma suit up and beat this thing

Comment: @JonathanLeaders If you have any issues come on back, I think we have a post or two on defeating the wall around here somewhere!

Comment: Its worth noting that you can lose part or all of your player house if the newly generated corruption manages to intersect with it.

Comment: I was able to beat it. Totally worth it. Would beat again.

Answer (score -3):

Anyway, the answer is **no**, as long as you don't have your character on normal mode.

When on normal setting for your character, you will lose the contents in your inventory as well as you're gear, so be careful with that!